# Advantage of Ethernet over other display interfaces in projection

Tags: film-industry, projection

As far as my knowledge goes, most people connect their PCs to their display whether a monitor of a projector using interfaces such as **VGA**, **HDMI**, or **DisplayPort**. Lately I found out that the in theaters the media server aka the device holding the movie like *Doremi servers* or *Dolby IMS* are connected to the projector using Ethernet cables.

What advantage does Ethernet offers over the connections stated above even though they are used in many professional settings.

Comment: Probably comes down to money. Cinemas have been using Ethernet for decades and nobody wants to rewire

Comment: Note that VGA is analog signaling and therefore has many disadvantages compared with HDMI and DVI, which are digital.

Comment: i also extend my display and input devices all over the shop via ethernet.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about movies or TV within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [technology questions about playing content are considered off-topic here.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection between *Doremi* server and *Christies* projector is (at least in the cinemas I know), not by Ethernet, but by external PCIe. Other installations/hardware generations may differ.

The projector has a custom interface board, the IMB (integrated Media Board), which handles movie decoding and decryption. The *Doremi* only reads the movie files from its RAID and sends it forward to the projector and the audio processor. The *Doremi* also has a Ethernet connection to the projector, but that is only control input (switch the lamp on/off, open/close the shutter, select inputs etc.).

Ethernet is used on the input side of the server, to ingest DCPs to its internal storage or to play live from external (central) storages in multi-screen centers.